# archlinux on virtual box: unable to connect to internet

Tags: virtual-machine, arch-linux

I am trying to install arch linux on virtual box.

I am using NAT connection

still inside archlinux when i try

```
ping google.com
```

nothing

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure because you have not given a lot of information, but the problem probably is that the virtual machine has not been assigned an IP address. The easiest way to resolve that is to use a DHCP client to dynamically assign the address, like [dhcpcd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dhcpcd). This is a standalone client, and it is already installed on the installation image.

If you want to run it in the installation image use

```
systemctl start dhcpcd
```

To make it always start on boot in your installed system (you will have to install the package first) use

```
systemctl enable dhcpcd
```

If you want further information, I recommend you read this article from the Arch wiki: [Network configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration). There you can also find information about network managers, programs that manage network configuration automatically.